# Python: How to change matrix indexing to cartesian indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indices, cartesian-coordinates

I have a matrix

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]])
```

And I want to represent a discrete 2D physical space on cartesian coordinates with it. So for example, when accessing the values I'd get `matrix[0,0] = 7`, `matrix[1,2] = 6`, `matrix[3,3] = 3`.

How can I accomplish that? I have tried using `np.meshgrid`, but as far as I have managed to implement it, the results are not what I am looking for. What I'm looking for could be accomplished by transposing the matrix every time I try to access a value, but I would like a way to just change the indexing of the matrix directly.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the logic, why 7, 6, 3? Does it continue? How does it generalize to larger arrays?

Comment: matrix[3, 3] is out of bounds.

Comment: @mozway The indexing is done from the bottom left, and I assume 3,3 should be 2,2.

Comment: can't change indexing

Comment: *I assume 3,3 should be 2,2* so what is [0,0]?

Comment: After beating my head against it a bit, @hpaulj is right - subclassing to change the indexing will break so many dependencies that your functionality will be nil, even if you try to fool the user by messing with `np.array_repr` to show them what they "expect" to see without changing the backend.

Comment: The meaning of row numbers is independent of how matrices are printed.  You can think of rows as going upward as they do in a Cartesian plane.  Even the interpretation of which dimension is the X and Y coordinates is merely a convention that is up to you.  There is only a discrepancy when you print a matrix, where numpy uses a different convention.  You don't need to define a "Carthesian" matrix, you simply need a function to print it with your own conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a view of your matrix with [`np.flip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html):

```
vmatrix = np.flip(matrix, axis=0)
print(vmatrix)

# Output
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Usage:

```
>>> vmatrix[0, 0]
7

>>> vmatrix[1, 2]
6

>>> vmatrix[2, 2]
3
```

You can also use [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
vmatrix = np.pad(np.flip(matrix, axis=0), [[1, 0], [1, 0]])
print(vmatrix)

# Output
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 7 8 9]
 [0 4 5 6]
 [0 1 2 3]]
```

Usage:

```
>>> vmatrix[1, 1]
7

>>> vmatrix[2, 3]
6

>>> vmatrix[3, 3]
3
```

You can also [Subclassing ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html) and override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the fact that `numpy.ndarray.__getitem__` is not writable, it is recommended to access the values in another way.

The `numpy.flip` function can be used to flip or reverse the order of elements in an array along a specified axis. This can be useful in various data processing and analysis tasks, such as image processing, signal processing, and data manipulation.

I would like to apologize to you for my previous incorrect response. The most optimal solution for this problem is to utilize the numpy.flip function.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of subclassing ndarray?

Comment: How can you say *"as it would create a copy of the array"* when the documentation said *"A view of m with the entries of axis reversed. Since a view is returned, this operation is done in constant time."*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have revised my answer and hope it does not cause any inconvenience to you.

Comment: Don't worry about that. Thanks for editing your answer :) I think `flip` could be a good answer (check my answer below) but I don't like too much `pad`. Subclassing is interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a solution to your problem. Although I will explain why the approach is very clunky and will lead to problem later in your experiments. I would advise to look at meshgrid for this. [Here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/meshgrids-and-disambiguating-rows-and-columns-from-cartesian-coordinates/) is a simple example how to perform computation on a 2D cartesian plane with meshgrid. I think this the standard and straightforward way, therefore the privilegied way to do that.

### The solution

Before, I will introduce some variables. The matrix which is meant to represent the cartesian plane between `x_values = np.arange(-2, 2+1)`, `y_values = np.arrange(-1, 1+1)`:

```py
matrix = np.array[
  [ 1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [ 3, 3, 0, 4, 4]]
```

We will denote the indices of this matrix as `i` and `j`. Also we will note `x` and `y` as our cartesian indices. What you want is a mapping from `(x, y)` to `(i, j)`. For example from `(2, 1)` you want the top left value with matrix indices `(0, 4)`.

The last introduced variable are `i_origin` and `j_origin`. Those variables are the `i` and `j` for the cartesian origin of the plane `(0, 0)`. We can do `i_origin = matrix.shape[0] // 2` and `j_origin = matrix.shape[1] // 2`. We wil use `i_origin` as an offset for the lines' indices - vertical - so for `y` and `j_origin` for `x`

If you take a pencil and a paper I think we can agree that:

```py
i = i_origin - y
j = j_origin + x
```

So, we can write the two short functions:

```py
def map_to_i(i_origin: int, y: int) -> int:
  return i_origin - y
def map_to_j(j_origin: int, x: int) -> int:
  return j_origin - x
```

If you want, we can even make a function to have a tuple of (i, j):

```py
def map_to_matrix_indices(i_origin: int, j_origin: int, x: int, y: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
  return map_to_i(i_origin, y), map_to_j(j_origin, x)
```

The we can simply write:

```py
>>> matrix[map_to_matrix_indices(i_origin, j_origin, 2, 1)]
2
```

### Problems

Well, we can say we have your solution, but this approach brings a bunch of problems:

- The interface of accessing/setting your values is not standard. As such, it might not work well with libraries. Plus, you lose a part of the broadcasting from numpy.
- One way to get around this would be to implement a class `CartesianMatrix` - for example - and put our functions in its method. You can inherit from or composed it from the `ndarray`. It might be feasible but needs additional work. (Note: it would be interesting to do actually)
- Written as such, it cannot be generalized for more dimension. I do think it can be easily formalized.

In general, you must set the interface of your new class the same as ndarray to have no problem. Else, you will have to find a workaround for every problem you encounter because you do not access/set indices by the standard way.

Note: interface of an object is how an object must behave.